# p7zip stuck at zipping (WARNING: No such file or directory )

Tags: zip, 7-zip

Basically, what I have found is that **p7zip** first scans the directory to be zipped and then zips those files in a single zip format.

Consider the following scenario, I have hundreds of GBs of files and folders which are first scanned to be zipped. Let's suppose I deleted a file after it has finished scanning. I don't know how a file can be missing by the time it finishes scanning but this behavior was seen in production, so in my local machine, I deleted it myself. In that case, it throws the following error and gets stuck indefinitely.

```
7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21                                                                                       
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,6 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9500T CPU @ 2.20GHz (906EA),ASM,AES-NI)                     
                                                                                                                                                              
Scanning the drive:                                                                                                                                           
29741 folders, 48865 files, 5035919485 bytes (4803 MiB)                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                              
Creating archive: /home/mymachine/Downloads.zip                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                              
Items to compress: 78606                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                              
WARNING: No such file or directory                                                                                                                            
/var/webarch/data/fs-root/538/2022/05/20/19964
```

So, is there any flag in p7zip or hack that can be used to ignore those warnings and continue zipping? Like, we can ignore a few of those files that are missing after scanning instead of throwing a timeout error in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was mentioned in bug report
[#2099 7z hangs if a file is deleted while creating a zip archive](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/2099/)
from 2017.

The developer promised to fix it, but didn't.

He did offer a workaround, which is to add the switch `-mmt1`,
which sets the number of threads to one (1).
Apparently, the hang is caused by multi-thread conflict when a file is not
found by one of the threads, and is avoided by having only one thread.

Comment: hey, thanks. but that would be very time-consuming. Any other tools like p7zip you recommend that don't have this kind of problem?

Comment: Surely this bug is specific to 7Zip and is not shared by other products.